# Listview Binding Does Not Update Programmatic Changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've done some research on the topic, and while I've come across some possibilities, nothing has worked for me.

**Details:**

I'm working on a WPF app using an MVVM design pattern. In the ViewModel, I have a `List` of `Notes`, a class with a few properties (among them, `Note`). I've created a property, `SelectedNote` on the `VM` to hold the currently selected note.

In my `View`, I've bound a `ListView` control to the list `QcNotes`. I've bound a `TextBox` to the `SelectedNote` property. When I make changes to the `TextBox`, they are correctly reflected in the appropriate row of the `ListView`.

**Problem:**

I've include a `RevertChanges` command. This is a relatively simple command that undoes changes I've made to the note. It correctly updates the `TextBox`, and it actually updates the underlying list correctly, but the changes do not update the `ListView` itself. (Is it necessary to use an `ObservableCollection` in this circumstance? I've been asked to try and resolve the problem without doing so).

**Attempted Fixes**

I tried to call `NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedNote")` and `NotifyPropertyChanged("QcNotes")` directly from within the call to `RevertChanges`, but that hasn't fixed the problem.

Any ideas?

**XAML**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <VM:MainProjectViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding QcNotes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="list" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNote}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Note" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Note}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <TextBox
          Height="30"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          Text="{Binding SelectedNote.Note, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
        />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="Allow Edits" Command="{Binding ChangeStateToAllowEditsCommand}" />
        <Button Content="Save Changes" Command="{Binding EditNoteCommand}" />
        <Button Content="Revert Changes" Command="{Binding RevertChangesToNoteCommand}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel Code**

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
  { 
        private QcNote selectedNote;
        private string oldNoteForUpdating;
        private VMState currentState;
        private string noteInput;
        private IList<QcNote> qcNotes;

        public IList<QcNote> QcNotes
        {
            get
            {
                return qcNotes;
            }
            set
            {
                qcNotes = value;
                NotifyPropertChanged();
            }
        }

        public QcNote SelectedNote
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedNote;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedNote = value;
                oldNoteForUpdating = SelectedNote.Note;
                NotifyPropertChanged();
            }
        }

        public VMState CurrentState
        {
            get
            {
                return currentState;
            }
            set
            {
                currentState = value;
                NotifyPropertChanged();
            }
        }

        public ICommand RevertChangesToNoteCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new ActionCommand(o => RevertChangestoNote());
            }
        }

        private void RevertChangestoNote()
        {
            QcNotes.First(q => q.Id == SelectedNote.Id).Note = oldNoteForUpdating;
            SelectedNote.Note = oldNoteForUpdating;
            NotifyPropertChanged("SelectedNote");
            NotifyPropertChanged("QcNotes");
            CurrentState = VMState.View;
        }
```

Comment: [`BindingGroups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindinggroup(v=vs.110).aspx) are made for the edit/revert scenario. Also, the first two lines of revert appear to do the same thing. `ObservableCollection` is only relevant in case of modifying the collection itself (add, remove, move, etc).

Comment: @H.B. Thanks for the input; I'll look into `BindingGroups`. The redundancy in `RevertChanges` was because I was trying different types of things to see what would stick. I'll be removing it. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post an answer to my own question, but don't want to deter other from offering suggestions.

I implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on my `Models.QcNote` class, and that resolved the issue. Initially, the interface was implemented exclusively on the `ViewModel`. In that case, `NotifyPropertyChanged` was only called when the `QcNote` object itself was changed, not when the properties of the object were changed.